# Is there any macro or pointer within ld.so which can give me address range of all the plt sections?

Tags: c, linux, compilation, linker, elf

I am modifying the `libc6` dynamic linker. For a given program which is run and all the shared libraries which are loaded with it I need the address range(start address + length) of all the respective `.plt` sections.

Is there any macro or pointers within the linker `ld.so` code which I can use for this purpose?
I am going through the linker code but due to lack of documentation in this perspective I am not able to figure out the exact element for my purpose. Google for it does not give any specific results which are useful for me.

Since linker does the initial loading and relocation it should have these information.
Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Is there a way to get section headers through linker? I can use them to get the `plt section` information.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you probably want to use [dl_iterate_phdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dl_iterate_phdr.3.html)

BTW, you should study the source code, and perhaps modify, [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org/); it is quite readable and has its own dynamic linker.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But through dl_iterate_phdr I will only get the info about the program headers and where they are loaded in vm. The plt section is loaded in the generally loaded with several other section like text, interp etc into a single load segment (2 one generally). So because of this I will only get the start and size of this entire load segment and not plt alone.